Why Use "You" Instead of "They" in this Sentence?
I came across this sentence in a book, Diary of a Wimpy Kid:

I've read that in ancient times they used to bury kings and pharaohs
with all their possessions. Back then I guess they thought you could
take your things with you into the afterlife.

I initially thought that since "they" is the subject, it would make more sense to write,

Back then I guess they thought they could take their things with them into the afterlife.

Using "you" here feels unusual but interesting, and I’m curious why "you" is natural.
Could you explain the effect or tone difference when using "you" instead of "they" in this kind of context? Thank you!

Since the dead person and the person who buries are definitely not the same, it would read slightly odd to use "they" for both of them. This is where variability in language is useful: if syntax and semantics are at odds with each other, you can switch to an alternative expression (such as generic "you" in place of generic "they") to satisfy both at the same time.

People can informally use 'you' to talk about people generically (that is, not about any particular person or people). In more formal speech or writing you will often find 'one' being used.
In olden times 'they' (people alive at the time) thought that a person who dies can take their possessions with them
Generic you (Wikipedia)

Seconded. I would note that both would be equally correct in the passage. Stylistically, the usage of 'you' here just makes it both more universal ("they thought [all people] could...") and also more immediate, in that the reader is being included in what those people thought, as well as being addressed by the narrator.

@Arbace - yes. The 'tone' of the whole piece is very informal (a kid's diary). In literature it is a sterotype that these are badly spelled, seldom punctuated, and severely informal.

They thought they could can mean they thought themselves the only people capable, or anyway had no opinion about others’ ability. Or that the speaker is not concerned with what they believed others to be capable of. Idiomatically, using you conveys the notion of one as in any person in general.

You can’t always get what you want.

If at first you don’t succeed, [you] try, try again.

"One" has an archaic or extremely posh ring to it in modern British English.

@JackAidley - the royal family are said to use it. I wouldn't say it waş 'posh' (whatever that means), though, just 'educated' or 'formal'. Not archaic at all.

@MichaelHarvey One must beg to differ :)

While there are definitely cases where 'they' could imply a limiting to inly those people, in this case I would still say that the ultimate meaning is the same. The 'they' in this case would be 'ancient peoples' but the 'they' the ancient peoples were thinking of would be all human beings. So ultimately the same implied meaning as 'any person in general'.

@Arbace IMO your additional insight about including the reader in the 'all people' group warrants its own answer.

I keep thinking of Max Bygraves singing 'Yew need haaands...' (that awful song).

The distinction between you/they in the example here does subtly change what is being said, but it doesn't change the core point being made. "They" distances them from us more so than "you". Answer this question: if we asked the ancient Egyptians if we (you and me today) could take our possessions into the afterlife, what would they say? (A) "Back then I guess they thought you could take your things" implies they thought this about every person. (B) "Back then I guess they thought they could take their things" implies they thought this about themselves, and maybe also us.

There is an old saying, "You can't take it with you".

This phrase dates from the early nineteenth century. Frederick Marryat used it in Masterman Ready (1841): “He was very fond of money; but that they said was all the better, as he could not take it away with him when he died.” The expression gained even wider currency when George Kaufman and Moss Hart used it as the title for one of their great comedies (1937)

I suspect that "you" is used because the expression is typically used for advice to someone who is unnecessarily frugal; "...I guess they thought you could take your things with you into the afterlife" resonates with the popular expression.

We can use 'you' for general observations, figures of speech, etc, that apply to everybody e.g. you can't get blood out of a stone, you can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear, you get what you pay for, and I think that 'you can't take it with you' may often be that type. It's  what I say when I spend some money rather than save it.
